# Using Class name as variable name in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class

I want to extend the UIView class by doing:

```
extension UIView {
    var UIImage:UIImage {
        get {
            let image = ....

            // ..... my code ....//

            return image

        }
    }
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

> 'UIImage' used within its own type

Anyone knows how to make it work?

PS: I know I can simply use a different name, but that is not what I am asking here.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why don't you just create a class function with a more meaningful name? What you do basically messes up the entire namespace. Just do `var image: UIImage { ...`

Comment: Education purposes. Also Apple uses that style to convert some types.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Never use class names when defining an ivar. Just do `var image: UIImage { ...` and call `myView.image`.

Comment: 2 examples:
let image = UIImage()    ...     
let  cgimage = image.CGImage!   ....   let   ciimage = image.CIImage!

Answer (score 1):

You need to qualify the property's type name with the package name:

```
extension UIView {

    var UIImage: UIKit.UIImage {
        let image = UIKit.UIImage()

        // ..... my code ....//

        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: `let image = UIKit.UIImage()`

Comment: Ok.  The extension is now accepted, but now it broke the normal usage of UIImage like in:   UIImage(named: "checkbox_checked")  with the error:  "Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIImage'".  Any idea?

Comment: `UIKit.UIImage(named: "checkbox_checked")`

Comment: Your property named `UIImage` now takes precedence over the UIKit type; everywhere you need to use `UIImage` in that class, you'll need to use the package-qualified name

Comment: Well, I would expect the UIImage property only work as a UIView property and not to simply override any UIImage calls in my project (I didn't mentioned by the UIImage(named: "checkbox_checked")  error was on a totally different file, it was not inside my extension). In that case, this solution in not practical at all. Thanks for the explanations Stuart.

Comment: @rsc: But was it in a `UIView` subclass? If so, that would explain why using `UIImage` by itself refers to the property.

Comment: @newacct, yes it was. And in the case, you are right, that is why the UIImage was now referring the property. Thanks for the clarification.